# save method in Mongoose failed

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I tried to use `save()` in Mongoose but saw empty collection been inserted.

my photo schema is like this :

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;

var photosSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    photos: {
        type: String
    },
    caption: {
        type: String
    }
});

var Photos = module.exports = mongoose.model('photos', photosSchema);

module.exports.getAllPhotos = function(callback){
    Photos.findAll(callback);
}
```

and in my route I do

```
var Photo = require('../models/photos');
router.post('/upload_photo', upload.any(), function(req, res, next) {
    var photo = new Photo();
    var data = {
        photos:'abc.jpg',
        caption:'something..'
    }
    photo.save(data);
    res.end();
});
```

Am I using `save` wrong here? I know I can define a method like savePhoto and export it, but how to use `save()` directly instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try it like so, i.e. pass the data directly to the constructor and end the response stream when the async. `save` finished (and maybe add error handling as well).

```
var photo = new Photo({
    photos:'abc.jpg',
    caption:'something..'
});
photo.save(function(err) {
    res.end();
});
```

There is also a shorthand `create` method on the model as described in the [Mongoose docs](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/models.html)

Answer (score 0):

Try like this, and you will be able to see the issue if there's any:

```
var data = {
    photos:'abc.jpg',
    caption:'something..'
};
var photo = new Photo(data);
photo.save(function (err) {
    if (err) console.log(err);
    res.end();
});
```